# Java EE HttpSession communication beetwen jsp and js

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

I want to adding something data in web page dynamically. I have a HttpSessionListener to keep all opened sessions.

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

ArrayList<HttpSession> sessions = new ArrayList<HttpSession>();

@Override
public void sessionCreated( HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent ) {
    sessions.add( sessionEvent.getSession() );
}

@Override
public void sessionDestroyed( HttpSessionEvent sessionEvent ) {
    sessions.remove( sessionEvent.getSession() );
}

public void sendToAll( Info info ) {
    for( HttpSession session: sessions ) {
        //send something to all connection clients.
    }
}
```

}

And how to get this messages from JavaScript client?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that of you do something like place a string on each session (or a list of pojos or a StringBuilder), and in your jsp you are templating that value, the next time you refresh the JSP page the values you pushed on the session will appear.

If you want to implement something like an http push, then I think you'll need to incorporate some other sort of technique whether client side ajax polling or comet.

Comment: I want to get effect like on facebook, when someone take a post, i get in dynamically without refresh page.

Comment: Well you need to look into ajax long polling or comet. Since you like spring, look into its new websockets support:http://assets.spring.io/wp/WebSocketBlogPost.html.  Long-polling would be a simpler solution, though you will have to expose the session object as an http endpoint.